# Swiper JS: scroll past the slider once reached the last slide

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I have a [vertical swiper slider](https://swiperjs.com/demos#vertical) which on mobile(only) takes almost full height on devices with smaller heights.

What I want to achieve is to allow user to scroll past the slider once they reach the end slide and still scroll further down.

I have set a codesandbox which explains my problem.
Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-vertical-forked-18ftz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

You can find a red area under the slider which becomes inaccessible on mobile phones when the height of the slide becomes `>`  mobile viewport.

**What I have found until now ?**

I found a property name which does exactly this `touchReleaseOnEdges`. According to the documentation if the value of `touchReleaseOnEdges` is set to o `true` then it ...

> Enable to release touch events on slider edge position (beginning,
> end) to allow for further page scrolling

But I am unable to make use of it to solve my problem.

How can I make this work ?